# What is causing apache to crash with the error "Inconsistency detected by ld.so"?

Tags: apache, crash, cross-compiling, glibc

I cross compiled apache httpd for a freescale powerpc chipset but as soon as I try to start apache I immediately get the following error:

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-deps.c: 622: _dl_map_object_deps: Assertion `nlist > 1' failed!
```

I've been trying to track down the source of this issue for days and all I've come up with is that it may have something to do with glibc. Any advice or information on what could be the cause or how to resolve would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug in glibc 2.13](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12454). Apparently it has been fixed about a year and a half ago, and you just need to upgrade to a version of glibc more recent than 2.13 (they're at 2.16 already).

Comment: I'm running eglibc, would the same bug exist in it as well?

Comment: `eglibc` is a fork of `glibc`, and they seem to be tracking changes in `glibc` fairly closely, so it is a safe bet that whatever bug exists in `glibc` 2.13 exists in `eglibc` 2.13 as well (the actual bug might have been introduced in an earlier version, so you might be running an earlier version as well).